# Преобразовать таблицу в массив объектов

Tags: javascript

Есть таблица с какими-то значениями. Как с помощью чистого js значения таблицы вывести в массив объектов? Чтобы получилось что вроде
arr = [{name:Вася, age:10}, {}]

```
<table id="grid">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th data-type="number">Возраст</th>
            <th data-type="string">Имя</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>Вася</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Петя</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>12</td>
            <td>Женя</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>9</td>
            <td>Маша</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Илья</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

Comment: как сопоставляется имя поля и значения? почему `name` и `age`?

Comment: Не совсем понимаю ваш вопрос. Потому что в одном столбце идут имена, а в другом возраст.

Comment: почему значением `name` должно быть именно Вася, а не 5? почему ключ вообще `name` называется?

Comment: Эм, мне кажется я чего-то не понимаю. Я просто из головы взяла. Я не понимаю какое значение имеет название ключа? У меня таблица контактов, в которой есть имя и возраст. Т.е. мне нужно что бы из каждой строки таблицы был объект, который будет включать в себя два ключа-значения- имя и возраст. Может я вообще не совсем то делаю, что надо? Я просто хочу добавить сортировку в таблицу, но для начала вроде как надо value таблицы записать в массив...

Answer (score 1):

```js
let tableElements = document.querySelectorAll("tbody > tr"), arrayWithData = [];

Array.from(tableElements, e => {
  let childNodes = e.getElementsByTagName("td");
  arrayWithData.push({
    age: +childNodes[0].textContent,
    name: childNodes[1].textContent
  });
});

console.log(arrayWithData);
```

```html
<table id="grid">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-type="number">Возраст</th>
      <th data-type="string">Имя</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>Вася</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Петя</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>Женя</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>Маша</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Илья</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```